# How to implement thresholded softmax in Keras?

Tags: keras, threshold, softmax

I would like to implement a threshold after the final softmax layer in a Keras-built classification problem so that class assignments with probability below some threshold alpha are disregarded (i.e. assigned to neither class). Would you be able to show me how to do that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is going to be used only in prediction, not in training (i.e. in the back-propagation algorithm), a typical and non-invasive way would be to predict the class probabilities via [`predict_proba`](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.0.0/models/sequential/) method and use them in your custom decisions. Once you obtain the predicted probabilities, you can define other rules of higher order complexity.